# Entity Framework 5 Automatic Code Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

In my current web project I'm trying to set up code migrations.  I set up my db initialiser as follows in my MVC4 project

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
}
```

I can make changes to my code first models and this updates the database to the latest automatic migration as expected when I start up the website.

However I'm trying to add an explicit migration through the console `Add-Migration FirstMigration` so I can add some indexes.  This adds the code file `201301071708126_FirstMigration` to my project and I can add in my index code here easily enough.

But this won't run automatically when I restart the website. I have to run `Update-Database` from the console to apply this migration.

[I followed this tutorial on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621) but I can't see what I'm doing wrong as it suggests to me that the explicit migration should run automatically.

In my configuration file I have the following constructor

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to this a little while ago and I missed out some information in the question.

I have 2 websites, an MVC app and a WEBAPI app.  I need to have the database initialisation in both otherwise it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score -1):

in my application constructor I have

`Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MYContext>());`

and it updates the model.

Comment: Read the question again.  I don't want to drop the database, I want to migrate it to the latest version so I don't lose the data.